# Use string methods to find and count vowels in a string?

Tags: java, string

I have this problem for homework (I'm being honest, not trying to hide it at least)
And I'm having problems figuring out how to do it.

Given the following declarations :   String phrase =  " WazzUp ? - Who's On FIRST ??? - IDUNNO";   Write the necessary code to 
count the number of vowels in the string and print appropriate message to the screen.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
String phrase =  " WazzUp ? - Who's On FIRST ??? - IDUNNO";
int i, length, vowels = 0;
String j;
length = phrase.length();
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

  j = phrase.substring(i, i++);
  System.out.println(j);

  if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("a") == true)
    vowels++;
  else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("e") == true)
    vowels++;
  else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("i") == true)
    vowels++;
  else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("o") == true)
    vowels++;
  else if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("u") == true)
    vowels++;

}
System.out.println("Number of vowels: " + vowels);
```

However, when I run it it just makes a bunch of blank lines. Can anyone help?

Comment: `String.charAt()` would be easier than `String.substring()` in this case.

Comment: Seems like a switch statement could be implemented here.

Comment: instead of switch it is better to create a list of vowels and then check whether list.contains(j)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`phrase.substring(i, i++);` should be `phrase.substring(i, i + 1);`.

`i++` gives the value of `i` and then adds 1 to it. As you have it right now, `String j` is effectively `phrase.substring(i, i);`, which is always the empty string.

You don't need to change the value of `i` in the body of the `for` loop since it is already incremented in `for (i = 0; i < length; i++)`.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to post. except I don't think the last increment is necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see the need to have a print statement in the loop.

```
String s = "Whatever you want it to be.".toLowerCase();
int vowelCount = 0;
for (int i = 0, i < s.length(); ++i) {
    switch(s.charAt(i)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            vowelCount++;
            break;
        default:
            // do nothing
    }
}
```

This converts the string to lowercase, and checks all the characters in the string for vowels.

Comment: Why create new lover case String in each loop iteration? Creating one before loop would be more effective IMHO.

Comment: `.toLowercase()` is wrong, it should be `.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 8):

This could/should be a one-liner

```
System.out.println("the count of all vowels: " + (phrase.length() - phrase.replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u", "").length()));
```

and its String only methods

Answer (score 4):

Improving on an above answer to consider vowels in caps:

```
System.out.println(s.length() - s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u|", "").length());
```

Answer (score 0):

The i++ increments i after is has been used, so you're essentially saying string.substring(i,i). Since the ending mark is exclusive, this will always return an empty string. An easy fix would be to just change it to

```
j = phrase.substring(i, ++i);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think there needs to be an increment operator either prefix or postfix. But yes its useful to know what the prefix and postfix operators do.

Answer (score 0):

Using Collections:

```
     String word = "busiunesuse";
     char[] wordchar= word.toCharArray();
     Character allvowes[] ={'a','e','i','o','u'};
     Map<Character, Integer> mymap = new HashMap();

     for(Character ch: wordchar)
     {
         for(Character vowels : allvowes)
         {
            if(vowels.equals(ch))
            {
             if(mymap.get(ch)== null)
             {
                 mymap.put(ch, 1);
             }
             else
             {
                 int val = mymap.get(ch);
                 mymap.put(ch, ++val);
             }
            }

         }
     }

     Set <Character> myset = mymap.keySet();
     Iterator myitr = myset.iterator();

     while(myitr.hasNext())
     {
         Character key = (Character) myitr.next();
         int value = mymap.get(key);
         System.out.println("word:"+key+"repetiotions:"+value);


     }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

***I know that's an old edit , 
but i think it's better if you use and array for the vowels :***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String phrase = " WazzUp ? - Who's On FIRST ??? - IDUNNO".toLowerCase();
    int vowels = 0;
    String[] array = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        String j = phrase.substring(i, i + 1);
        System.out.println(j);
        for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
            if (j.equals(array[n])) {
                vowels++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of vowels: " + vowels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To **Count number of Vowels** in a String:

```
class Test {  

      static int a;

      public static String countVowel(String strName) { 

          char ch[] = strName.toCharArray();


          for(int i=0; i<ch.length; i++) {

            switch(ch[i]) {

            case 'a':

             a++;   

            break;      

            case 'e':
                a++;    

                break;

            case 'i':
                 a++;   

                break;

            case 'o':
                 a++;   

                break;

            case 'u':
                 a++;   

                break;

            }

          }

          strName = String.valueOf(a);

          return strName;       
      } 

      public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(countVowel(s.nextLine())); 
     }   

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late but maybe this response could help other people in the future if they're working with accents

To avoid problems we can normalize the input text to NFD with [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) which separates the accents (be: umlauts, grave accent, acute accent, circumflex accent, etc.) in letter and accent.

**Example:** `"schön" ----NFD----> "scho\u0308n"`

The solution is

1. Normalizing the text with [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) and replace the accents with ([`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)))
2. Convert text to lowercase
3. Replace everythin that isn't a vowel (or anything you want to count)

```java
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class Main {
    private static String str = "This ïs a téxt with vòwêls";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Normalizing the text
        // Replacing all the accents
        // Convert to lowercase
        String text = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                .replaceAll("[\\u0300-\\u036f]", "")
                .toLowerCase();

        // We replace everything but vowels
        int vowels_count = text.replaceAll("[^aeiou]", "").length();

        System.out.printf("%s%s%s %d %s",
                "\nThe text \"",
                str,
                "\" has",
                vowels_count,
                "vowels"
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

public class JavaApplication2 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Enter some text");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine().toLowerCase();

    char[] vowel = new char[]{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int[] countVowel = new int[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
        char c =input.charAt(j);
        if(c=='a')
            countVowel[0]++;
        else if(c=='e')
            countVowel[1]++;
        else if(c=='i')
            countVowel[2]++;
        else if(c=='o')
            countVowel[3]++;
        else if(c=='u')
            countVowel[4]++;


    }
     for (int i = 0; i <countVowel.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Count of vowel " + vowel[i] + "=" + countVowel[i]);
        }

    }
}
```