# Android searching for a character in a string

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am developing a programme .. in android where a name is entered in edittext and vowels are searched in it. suppose in name Roshan vowels are present and ie o&a and from which the first vowel has to be displayed I got the code for displaying the first vowel and the programme is working fine.. but the programme is displaying the vowel only when there is more than one vowel ..if there is only one vowel that letter is not displaying.. pls check the code   and if found any mistake pls help..

```
public char gReport(View V) 
            {
                et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
                et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
                et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);


                String str = et1.getText().toString();


                int a=str.indexOf('a');
                int b=str.indexOf('e');
                int c=str.indexOf('i');
                int d=str.indexOf('o');
                int e=str.indexOf('u');

                if(a!=-1 && a<(b&c&d&e)) 
                {
                    tv1.setText("a");
                }
                else if(b!=-1 && b<(a&c&d&e)) 
                    {

                    tv1.setText("e");

                    }
                else if(c!=-1 && c<(a&b&d&e)) 
                {

                tv1.setText("i");

                }
                else if(d!=-1 && d<(a&c&b&e)) 
                {

                tv1.setText("o");

                }
                else if(e!=-1 && e<(a&c&d&b)) 
                {

                tv1.setText("u");

                }
                return 0;



    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `a<(b&c&d&e)`

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734630/use-string-methods-to-find-and-count-vowels-in-a-string

Comment: the first coming vowel has to be displayed... so that i wrote like that

Comment: `&` is a bitwise AND, you probably want `b+c+d`.

Comment: So you want to ensure that the position of the current vowel is the smallest integer. Well that's your problem

Comment: yes...but now what happening is if more than one vowel in the entered string then first vowel will display but only one vowel is there then it will not display..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `if` condition I assume you want to check if the current vowel index is smaller than all the others. You can't do it the way you wrote. You have to explicitly write for each case:

```
if((a!=-1) && (a<b) && (a<c) && (a<d) && (a<e))
```

however, this won't work since your index will be greater than the erronous index (-1). So, you have to include a temporary integer value to check the minimum of the indexes. Try this:

```
int min = str.length();
if(a!=-1 && a<min) {
    tv1.setText("a");
    min=a;
}
if(b!=-1 && b<min) {
    tv1.setText("e");
    min=b;
}
if(c!=-1 && c<min) {
    tv1.setText("i");
    min=c;
}
if(d!=-1 && d<min) {
    tv1.setText("o");
    min=d;
}
if(e!=-1 && e<min) {
    tv1.setText("u");
    min=e;
}
```

Comment: You need to change all the comparisons in your if statements `e!=-1 && a<min` should be `e!=-1 && e<min`

Comment: Thanks Nitro for reply let me check

Comment: Thanks @ScottHelme , I thought I'd mastered the c/p technique ;)

Answer (score 2):

to find first occurance of vowel

```
String str = et1.getText().toString();

       outer : for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
        switch(s.charAt(i)) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        tv1.setText(s.charAt(i));
        break outer;
        }
```

or like this..

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            {
if(StringUtils.isVowel(str,i)){
 tv1.setText(s.charAt(i));
            break;
}
}
```

Comment: Neither of these will find the first vowel in the string, but instead the last. You need to invert the counter in your for loops: `for (i = str.length(); i > 0 ; i--)`

Comment: @ScottHelme did you notice the `break;` statement..? it will find the first occurrence of vowel and then exit the loop.. :)

Comment: Won't the `break` just exit the `switch`?

Comment: @ScottHelme I understand what you meant now... updated the first case.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a flaw in your logic.

```
if(a!=-1 && a<(b&c&d&e))
```

You're saying, if `a != -1` - this means it found the vowel in the string.

Followed by, `&& a<(b&c&d&e)` - you're trying to find if it's the lowest index.

What if `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are `-1`. `a` will never be less than them. This is why it does not work when there is only 1 character found.

NitroNbg beat me to the answer, I've made a comment on there and that should resolve your problem.

Comment: thanks Scott...u r explanation helped me to know my mistake.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this::

In java you have one method that used for searching particular string in your given string.

```
YourString.contains("CheckString");
```

For checking First vowel just find the minimum number from the array and then get substring from the main string.

```
char[] a = {'3', '5', '1', '4', '2'};

List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(a));

System.out.println(Collections.min(b));
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: but I want to display the first vowel in the string

Comment: Can you plz elaborate your method... :)

Comment: in this method when we will get min of all indexes. so we can get char at min index in the string and set it as text in textview.