# How to count the number of consonants in a String in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that counts the number of vowels and consonants from a sentence entered by the user. My code below counts the number of vowels but it give me strange numbers for consonant counts. For example if i enter "g" I get consonant count being 10.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
    String sentence = scan.nextLine();

    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int consCount = 0;
    int i;

      for(i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i += 1){
        char currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
        int index;
        for(index = 0; index < vowels.length(); index += 1){
          if(vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar)){
            vowelCount++;
          }else if(Character.isLetter(currentChar) && (vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar))){
            consCount++;
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println(consCount);
      System.out.println(vowelCount);
  }   
}
```

Comment: check this line -- if(Character.isLetter(currentChar) && (vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar)))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use string methods to find and count vowels in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734630/use-string-methods-to-find-and-count-vowels-in-a-string)

Comment: shouldn't second if be like this if(Character.isLetter(currentChar) && (vowels.charAt(index) != (currentChar)))

Comment: Side note: if you convert your input to lower-case, you only need to check for `"aeiou"`. Also `i += 1` is traditionally written as `i++` in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I have also improved it, see `vowels.indexOf` (instead of manual iteration) and the line with `isLetter` (corrected wrong check on vowels) and output (added `;`) and `i++`.

```
public class VowelCount{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
    String sentence = scan.nextLine();

    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int consCount = 0;
    int i;

    int length = sentence.length();
    for(i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        char currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (vowels.indexOf(currentChar)>=0)
           vowelCount++;
        else if(Character.isLetter(currentChar))
                consCount++;
    }
    System.out.print(consCount+";");
    System.out.print(vowelCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: @sina72 New users cannot up-vote. Acceptance is also delayed until 15 minutes have passed.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the final solution guys :)**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelConsCount
{ public static void main(String args[])
    { System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String sentence = in.nextLine();

      String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
      int vowelCount = 0;
      int consCount = 0;
      int i;

      for(i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i ++)
         { char currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
           if (vowels.indexOf(currentChar)>=0)
                vowelCount++;
           else if(Character.isLetter(currentChar))
                consCount++;
         }
      System.out.print("\nNumber of vowels is "+vowelCount);
      System.out.print("\nNumber of consonant is "+consCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please also add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In that line:
`else if(Character.isLetter(currentChar) && (vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar))){`
you are checking if your char is a letter and also if it's a vowel. You could try that in the condition test:

```
else if(Character.isLetter(currentChar)){
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with else part of your inner for-loop.

```
boolean isVowel(char c){
   String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
   for(int index = 0; index < vowels.length(); index += 1)
   if(vowels.charAt(index) == c)
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

Now after you get the currentChar just try this

```
if(isVowel(currentChar))
   vowelCount++;
else
   constCount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several issue with your code:

1. You are using `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` which makes reading number misleading.
2. You are looping over possible vowels and incrementing `vowelCount` if vowel is found but **incrementing consCount if not !**. You should split the two: first checking vowels, then consonants.

   ```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
   String sentence = scan.nextLine();

   String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
   int vowelCount = 0;
   int consCount = 0;
   int i;
   System.out.println("["+sentence+"]");
   for (i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i += 1)
   {
       char currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
       boolean isVowel = false;
       int index;
       for (index = 0; index < vowels.length(); index += 1)
       {
           if (vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar))
           {
               vowelCount++;
               isVowel =true;
               break;//we found the vowel, no need to keep looping
           }
       }

        if (!isVowel && Character.isLetter(currentChar))//vowel have not been found
       {
           consCount++;
       }

   }

   System.out.println("cons: " + consCount);
   System.out.println("vowel: " + vowelCount);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
    String sentence = scan.nextLine();

    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int vowelCount = 0;
    int consCount = 0;
    int i;
    boolean flag;
      for(i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i += 1){
        char currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
        flag=false;
        int index;
        for(index = 0; index < vowels.length(); index += 1){
          if(vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar)){
            vowelCount++;
            flag=true;
            continue;
          }
        }
        if(!flag && Character.isLetter(currentChar) ){
            consCount++;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(consCount);
      System.out.println(vowelCount);
```

**changes**

What you were doing :

```
 for(index = 0; index < vowels.length(); index += 1){
  if(vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar)){
      vowelCount++;
    }else if(Character.isLetter(currentChar) && (vowels.charAt(index) == (currentChar))){
        consCount++;
  }
```

in there the `consCount` getting increased every time it doesn't match with a vowel.
for example if you try `hello` the `consCount` will be increased to 10 for only `h` as it doesn't math with any vowels.

so what i did here is  i put the `consCount++` outside the 2nd for loop and add an `flag` to check whether its an vowel or not. If its an vowel then  `consCount++` will be skipped and if not then it will be checked for latter the considered as an consonant.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner stringin = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string1;
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    string1 = stringin.nextLine();
    string1 = string1.toLowerCase();

    int count = 0;
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;
    int spaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {

        char letter = string1.charAt(i); 
        if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || 
                letter == 'i' || letter == 'o' ||
                    letter == 'u')
        {
            vowels++;
        }
        else if  (letter == ' ')
        {
            spaces++;
        }
        else
        {
            consonants++;


        }
    }
    System.out.print("The number of vowels is " + vowels);
    System.out.print(" The number of consonants is " + consonants);
}
```

Here is my solution. I had to make a exception for space as it got counted as a consonant. Currently taking a class in Java, so I am not experienced at all.