# counting the number of consonants in a string

Tags: java, string, function, bluej

My objective is to count the number of consonants ***ONLY***, in a String,and this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Program46 here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Program46
{
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter phrase: ");
        String phrase=br.readLine();
        int lth=phrase.length();
        int ctr=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=lth-1;i++)
        {
            char a=phrase.charAt(i);
            boolean chk=Character.isDigit(a);
            if(a!='a'&&a!='e'&&a!='i'&&a=='o'&&a!='u'&&a!=' '&& chk==false)
                ctr++;

        }
        System.out.println("No. of consonents: "+ctr);
    }
}
```

The program does compile,showing no syntax error.
However,when I execute this in void main(),
no matter what I input,the number of consonants it counts is always 0.
Is there any error in my program? If so,I request you suggest a better way to do this,or a way to correct the above code.

Comment: Fix this, and the code will work: `&&a=='o'` should be `&&a!='o'`. I am voting to close as a typo. Consider deleting the question if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. You have a typo when checking for the vowel 'o'.  Instead of `a == 'o'`, it should be `a != 'o'`
2. Even if you fix this, your check only considers LOWER CASE vowels, a space character, and numbers.  If the character being checked is not anyone of these then it'll be counted as a consonant.  That includes UPPER CASE vowels, special characters (!@#$ etc...), other space characters ('\t'), and punctuation.

The corrections could something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter phrase: ");
    String phrase = br.readLine();
    int lth = phrase.length();
    int ctr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= lth - 1; i++) {
        char ch = phrase.charAt(i);
        // Skip this character if it's not a letter
        if (!Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch != 'a' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u' &&
            ch != 'A' && ch != 'E' && ch != 'I' && ch != 'O' && ch != 'U' ) {
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No. of consonents: " + ctr);
}
```

Once you reach this point, you can look into ways of "improving" the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an accidental check that the current character **is** `'o'` (`a=='o'`), instead of checking that it **isn't** (`a != 'o'`).

Fix that and you should be fine.

BTW, note that the proper signature of the `main` method in Java is `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262270/how-to-count-the-number-of-consonants-in-a-string-in-java . please go through this link you will get best solution . Thanks

Comment: @Mureinik That's an alternative for what I use. It works the same however.