# How to find vowels in a given string?

Tags: java

Just a simple code I'm trying to do.

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
if ( word.indexOf(vowels.toLowerCase()) == -1 ){
        return word+"ay";
}
```

I've tried using this code for checking if a word has no vowels and if so adds "ay" to it. So far no luck. I think my problem is somewhere around the indexOf method, can anyone explain it a bit more to me?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this with the use of indexOf.

Comment: Your code looks for the entire set of vowels in the word, not for the occurrence of at least one. This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734630/use-string-methods-to-find-and-count-vowels-in-a-string

Comment: again, I know how to solve this usual .equals I need help on the use of indexOf

Comment: then iterate on the string of vowels, one by one using indexOf for each vowel

Comment: is there a more efficient way of doing this? I understand what you are saying I'm just looking for efficiency

Comment: Don't use .indexOf if you want efficiency

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public String ModifyWord(String word){
    String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
    for (String v : vowels) {
        if(word.indexOf(v) > -1){ // >-1 means the vowel is exist
           return word;
        }
    }
    return word+"ay"; //this line is executed only if vowel is not found
}
```

Comment: Sorry what does the middle line do? if(word.indexOf(v) > -1){

Comment: `if(word.indexOf(v) > -1)` check if vowel **is exist**, once you found the first vowel (if exist) you don't have to proceed check anymore

Comment: Why would the +"ay" be added outside?

Comment: @JackNguyen this line, `return word+"ay";` only be reached when there is no vowel found (in which you want to add `ay`). if your word contains vowel, your method will stop at `return word;`(in which you don't want to add anything)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, and [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). First, a regular expression. The `[AEIOUaeiou]` is a [vowel character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and the `.*`(s) are to consume any optional non-vowel(s).

```
String regex = ".*[AEIOUaeiou].*";
```

Then you can test your `word` like

```
if (word.matches(regex)) {
```

**Note** your `vowels` are already lowercase (no need to lowercase `word` here, the regular expression includes uppercase).