# My program will not count the vowels

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment that needs to count the vowels in the string.  My program is running, but will not ignore consonants and spaces.  Is there something I am missing in the code?

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean stopProgram = false;
    while(!stopProgram == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a Word or \"q\" to end the program: "); // prompt the user for input
        Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = wordScanner.nextLine();
        if(!word.equals("q")) {
            String vowels[] = {"a","e","i","o","u","y","A","E","I","O","U","Y"}; //define upper and lower case vowels
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[0]) ||
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[1]));
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[2]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[3]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[4]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[5]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[6]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[7]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[8]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[9]);
                        String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[10]);
String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[11]);

                        count++;
                }
            System.out.println(("The Vowel Count is: ") + count);   
            }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're seperating your `if` condition with semi-colons `;` instead of or `||`. Check the format of your `if` to make sure the different conditions are properly seperated, and that the conditions are properly enclosed (and doesn't have a semi-colon after the closing paranthesis).

Comment: Also, you can iterate through your vowels array with a nested for-loop to make it more readable

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13734724/1079354; while it feels like a dupe your code has problems of its *own* which are worth fixing in their own right.

Answer (score 2):

That's your if-statement:

```
if(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[0]) ||
                    String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[1]));
```

You break the if statement by the `;` at the very end.

After that, there are a lot of statements (whose result is ignored)

```
 String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[1]));
```

which are not part of the if statement anymore.

Then, you increment count with every iteration - regardless of the if, it's interrupted by said `;`.

Answer (score -2):

First you should make your code a bit cleaner : create your list of vowels outside of your while so that you won't create it at each iteration, then use maybe a double for loop to run through your tab of vowels :

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean stopProgram = false;
    String vowels[] = {"a","e","i","o","u","y","A","E","I","O","U","Y"}; //define upper and lower case vowels
    while(!stopProgram == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a Word or \"q\" to end the program: "); // prompt the user for input
        Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = wordScanner.nextLine();
        if(!word.equals("q")) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 12; ++j){
                    if(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(vowels[j]){
                        ++count;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        System.out.println(("The Vowel Count is: ") + count);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The double loop isn't necessary, and using a constant to loop over the array of vowels is also very bad form.

Comment: I didn't say it was terrible, but it's always cleaner to avoid code repetition as 11 call of the same function. And by doing that, it would have also solved @Nathan 's problem :) (since there is no use for '||' anymore).

Comment: No, you misunderstand me.  Suppose I decide to remove Y as a vowel.  What do you think will happen with your code?

Comment: well you're right, it would be even better to use vowels.length() instead